# SQL Where clause in PHP not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am new to php so hopefully someone could point out where i am going wrong
I have written a php code to fetch certain records from an MySQL database

I am running the query as

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Messages where Id='idLo'") 
or  die(mysql_error());
```

i get no results
but when i hard code like

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Messages where Id='4'") 
or  die(mysql_error());
```

It returns all the data
What am i misisng
i am collecting idLo as a get parameter

```
$idLo = $_GET['id'];
```

Comment: Did you spend a few seconds searching? this has been answered so many times.

Comment: Yes i tried maybe i searched it wrongjust started coding on php today
Coudnt realise this silly mistake
All the answers below work fine
Thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code needs to change to

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Messages where Id='$idLo'") or  die(mysql_error());
```

From

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Messages where Id='idLo'") or  die(mysql_error());
```

There is basic thing that in php every variable has dollar( $ ) sign that we need to use every time while using it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
`$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Messages where Id='$idLo'");`

Comment: You are recommending using a depreacted function

Comment: @nrathaus, OP is welcome to use whatever function he wishes. This corrects his error.

Comment: And? He is clearly working with `mysql_` functions. If I wrote `mysqli_`, it will not work, as he `mysql_connect`ed. Now remove that downvote.

Comment: Helping him use code that will soon stop working isn't a helpful answer even if it solves his problem "now"

Comment: I didn't give you any downvote, and even if I did, I still think your answer isn't good, yes he used mysql_query, so tell him DONT use it

Comment: I think he should learn PHP first, not the difference between mysql and mysqli.

Comment: I wish I could downvote comments.

Comment: I really think and you can think otherwise, that if a person is just learning PHP, he should do so from the start with the right "functions" learning to use some deprecated function (and insecure as well), from day 1 is just plain wrong.

Comment: He did not know that variable values are reached using `$`. It is the very beginning, the first lesson, the first hello world app of every PHP programmer. Would you bother him with MySQLi being object oriented, more flexible and secure, while the MySQL driver is deprecated in some PHP versions? He might not know that there are more versions at all. He is definately far away for OOP. He's struggling to get something work. He is eventually going to learn it on his own, but you shouldn't drop someone into the deep water and sharks to learn swimming. He's gonna give it up.

Answer (score 1):

you forgot `$` in front of `idLo` in your query.

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Messages where Id='".$idLo."'");
```

should do it

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you haven't included the "$" to signify that idlo is a variable:

```
where Id='idLo'
```

should be

```
where Id='$idLo'
```

Also, you might want to have a look into using PDO or Mysqli for accessing your mysql database through PHP.

Answer (score 0):

you should user mysqli pr PDO by now. A bit better:

```
$result = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM Messages where Id='$id'");
```

also, check if Id is really with capital letters and add a dollar sign to the variable name.

Answer (score 0):

```
$idLo = $_GET['id'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Messages where Id='$idLo'") or die(mysql_error());
```